# Let $\mathcal C$ the unit circle. Does $\mathcal C=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}=\{(\cos(t),\sin(t))\mid t\in [0,2\pi)\}$ are really equality?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal C$ be the unit circle. Does $$\mathcal C=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}=\{(\cos(t),\sin(t))\mid t\in [0,2\pi]\}=\{e^{it}\mid t\in [0,2\pi]\}$$ are really equality ? Because they all represent the unit circle, but the don't really seems to leave in the same space. For example, $\{1+i+e^{it}\mid t\in [0,2\pi]\}$ is also a unit circle, but centred in an other point. So, $$\mathcal C=\{1+i+e^{it}\mid t\in [0,2\pi]\},$$
should hold as well. But I'm not so sure if it should be an equality as set, or rather a sort of "isomorphe" equality, i.e. that there is some bijective map that preserve the structure (in some way...)

Sorry if my question is not clear. For me, things are a bit unclear as well.

Answer (score 3):

The sets$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}\text{ and }\{(\cos t,\sin t)\mid t\in[0,2\pi)\}$$are the same set, yes. Whether or not they are equal to $\{e^{it}\mid t\in[0,2\pi]\}$, that depends upon how you define $\mathbb C$. If you define it in such a way that the sets $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are equal, then the answer is affirmative. Otherwise, it is negative.

However you should keep in mind that, when we talk about “unit circle”, that means the circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$.

Comment: Thank you. When you say : unit circle is centered at $(0,0)$. This make the circle depend of the chart, no ? Wheres, I thought that a manifold is not dependent of a Chart. For example, $\{(t,t)\mid t\in [0,1]\}$ or $\{(2t,2t)\mid t\in [0,1/2]\}$ has the same trace, no ? So, it should be the same manifold, no ?

Comment: I am not talking about manifolds here, and the concept of unit circle doesn't make sense on a manifold. What I am saying is that, in $\mathbb C$, **the** unit circle is the circle with radius $1$ centered at $0$.

Comment: @Surb But both sets are compact (?) (and also the same set)

Comment: Wrong. These sets are equal (and both of them are compact). But, if you think that they're different, then provide an example of a point that belongs to one of them but not to the other one.

Comment: I think that both $A\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ and $B\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ are connected. Actually, both of them are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I use the fact that $(cos(t),\sin(t))=(\cos(t-2\pi),\sin(t-2\pi))$.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but, as you wrote, it's something completely different here.